# how can i fix this error "Exception raised during rendering: Could not find dimen resource matching value 0x1050050"?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

When opened in an activity layout normally, the preview should appear, which should again show the preview of the layout.
But no preview is shown,
Does anyone know how solve this?
[here is screen of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIvRx.png)

Here is the error:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not find dimen
>   resource matching value 0x1050050 (resolved name:
>   config_scrollbarSize) in current configuration.   at
>   android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1145)
>     at
>   android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1121)
>     at
>   android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1125)
>     at
>   android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getDimensionPixelSize(Resources_Delegate.java:657)
>     at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getDimensionPixelSize(Resources.java:724)
>     at android.view.ViewConfiguration.(ViewConfiguration.java:366)
>     at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:452)   at
>   android.view.View.(View.java:4806)  at
>   android.view.View.(View.java:4948)  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:659)     at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:248)     at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:244)     at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:240)     at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:236)     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.(Layout.java:133)  at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:288)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:391)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:195)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:540)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$5(RenderTask.java:666)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 1):

It tells that config_scrollbarSize is not found in your dimens.xml file. make sure you have that in dimens.xml. Because you are using that value somewhere in that layout.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while. But, had the same issue, launched VS as administrator and the issue is gone.